# Use string attribute to override hashCode function

Tags: java, string, hashcode

In the code below I want to use the "term" attribute to generate the hash code. How to use this String attribute to generate hash code?

```
class Term {
    String term;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Term) {
            return this.term.equals(((Term)o).term);
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`String#hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) method with a `null` check. That would be enough:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int prime = 31;
    return prime + (term == null ? 0 : term.hashCode());    
}
```

You should also modify the `equals()` method to do the `null` check on `this.term` before hand.

Comment: @user949300 Good catch. Fixed it.

Comment: There is no need to modify the equals() method because instanceof will return false if the argument is null.

Comment: @SlavaSt I'm talking about the case when `this.term` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Objects` if you use JDK 1.7 or more.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() { 
   int prime = 31;
   return prime + Objects.hashCode(this.stringAtrribute);    
}
```

For multiple attributes:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() { 
   int prime = 31;
   return prime + Objects.hash(this.attributOne,this.atrributeTwo);    
}
```

And yes ofcourse as with the previous answers the `equal` and `hashcode` method should have consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can write this code for you. Just choose Generate hashCode and equals from the Source menu.